# sql query to summarize a table with mean and variance

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 3 columns named A, B, and C. Let *a* be a value from column A, *b* from column B. I want to create a new table with 4 columns having values  *a*, *b*, *mean of values of column C where A=a and B=b*, *variance of values of column C, where A=a and B=b*. The new table will have as  many rows as the number of unique *(a,b)* pairs.  How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will fetch the values.  You can use the MySQL `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax if you want to select the results into another table.

```
SELECT A, B, AVG(C) AS C_mean, VARIANCE(C) AS C_variance
FROM table_name
GROUP BY A, B
```

Comment: How to use the `select into` query? I tried  `SELECT A, B, AVG(C) AS C_mean, VARIANCE(C) AS C_variance FROM table_name GROUP BY A, B into outfile 'out.txt'` but I got all zeros in the out.txt file.

Comment: That looks correct to me.  Does the query (without `INTO`) work as you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure then. :/  I don't use `SELECT INTO` very frequently, sorry.

Comment: The mysql manual (5.1) says _MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE_. So I tried the outfile option.

Comment: Ah, right.  The MySQL syntax is `INSERT INTO table (a, b, c, d) SELECT ...`.

Comment: `select ... into outfile file_name` worked correctly. It was a path problem earlier.